# Normalization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

Besides of the title, I believe that my question is easy for Rails experts.

I'm trying to normalize my Rails app as much as I can. Instead of having a table called "Users", I have three tables: "Users", "Studios" and "Musicians". Studios and Musician are users, but (belongs_to) and Users can have one Studio and one Musician (has_one, for both).

So far so good, but how do I let "Users" edit their "Musician" columns ?

In which controller I must do it ?

Before ask "Why don't you make roles?". Well, Musicians have many attributes that Studios don't have, and the opposite is true as well.

This knowledge is important for my application, because I ll let Studios create "Rooms" (Studio has_many Rooms) and "Rooms" will have "Appointments" (room has_many appointments) and in the end, Users can make Appointments (Users has_many)

I don't know how to create the structure, and how it would be in the controllers. If anyone could help me it would be greate. I'm using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have has_one and belongs_to between users and musicians you can always access the musician object associated with a user object directly and edit accordingly. For example :

```
last_created_user = User.last
musician = last_created_user.musician
```

That if every user has a musician, if it doesn't find the corresponding musician it will return nil. works similarly studio too. Thats the beauty of rails :)

PS : Just a curiosity.Are you actually a musician ? ;)

Comment: I can edit an User "Musician" attribute with the User controller "edit" simply doing @musician = User.find(params[:id]).musician ? And how I would let a Studio create a room ? User.find(params[:id]).studio.Room.new ? Thanks for the reply and actually, I'm just a music lover :D

Comment: Yes . i would suggest you to go through active record associations once before stepping in. There are more than one method to do that creation. You can use User.find(bla bla).studio.room = Room.create(...). I might be wrong wit syntax. Better to go through them once .

And asked because am a music enthusiast/player as well !

Comment: What you mean with "go through active record associations", there is any tutorial or something like that ? I have doubts how it would be the migrations, I have to add the foreign keys myself right ? Like, in Musician, have an "user_id"... Well if you speak portuguese, I would reccomend my Music Blog :D

Comment: Ahh...I don't understand Portugese :) . And about the tutorials you can just go through the rails website. It has a section explaining the active record stuffs. Else you will always find a lot of explanation by googling. I would suggest you go through rails website first.